# Share a folder between two jobs in CircleCI

Tags: circleci

I am setting up a continuous integration of a node project and I am unable to share a folder between two different jobs.

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: circleci
      - deploy:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: circleci
          requires:
            - build
```

Is there a way to share the /dist folder from 'build' job to the 'deploy'
job?

Comment: Yes, you need [workspaces](https://circleci.com/blog/deep-diving-into-circleci-workspaces/). See also [the docs here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/concepts/#workspaces-and-artifacts).

Comment: @halfer This should be an answer.

Comment: Yep @FelicianoTech. I sometimes comment to see if something helps, and then expand on it later if I get positive feedback. If you want to add a more substantial answer straight away, go ahead `:-)`.

Comment: I found a way of doing it using attach and persist workspaces.I found the example in this demo repository: https://github.com/enkidevs/circleci-share-data-between-jobs